# Is it possible to know what changes have been included in an OS X Update?

Tags: macos

My computer just downloaded an OS X update. Is it possible to know what's been changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provides support articles with a high-level overview of the changes in an operating system update. For example, [here's the one for Mac OS X 10.6.5](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4250):

> **What's included?**
>
> General fixes and improvements
>
> - Improves reliability with Microsoft Exchange servers.
> - Addresses performance of some image-processing operations in iPhoto and Aperture.
> - Addresses stability and performance of graphics applications and games.
> - Resolves a delay between print jobs.
> - Addresses a printing issue for some HP printers connected to an AirPort Extreme.
> - Resolves an issue when dragging contacts from Address Book to iCal.
> - Addresses an issue in which dragging an item from a stack causes the Dock to not automatically hide.
> - Resolves an issue in which Wikipedia information may not display correctly in Dictionary.
> - Improves performance of MainStage on certain Macs.
> - Resolves spacing issues with OpenType fonts.
> - Improves reliability with some Bluetooth braille displays.
> - Resolves a VoiceOver issue when browsing some websites with Safari 5.
> - Improves Bluetooth pairing with Magic Trackpad.
> - Resolves performance issues with third-party displays that use InstaPort technology.
> - Add SSL support for transferring files with iDisk.
> - Resolves an issue when opening 4-up Photo Booth pictures in Preview.
> - Addresses keyboard responsiveness issues in the Dock when Spaces is turned on.
> - Resolves an issue syncing Address Book with Google.
> - Fixes an issue when replying to a Mail message sent by a person whose name contains certain characters such as é or ü.
> - Improves performance for users bound to an Active Directory domain.
> - Improves reliability of Ethernet connections.
> - Systems with a Mac Pro RAID Card (Early 2009) installed can now be put to sleep. For more information, see [Mac Pro RAID Card (Early 2009): Enabling system sleep](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4266).
> - Improves reliability of fibre channel connections, resolving a potential Xsan volume availability issue.
> - Adds RAW image compatibility for [additional](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3825) digital cameras.
> - Security improvements; for information about the security content of this update, please visit [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1222).